# Configuring jobs using Artifactory in Jenkins with Jenkins Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, artifactory, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to set up [Artifactory](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) in a Jenkins job that is generated with the [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin).

The configuration looks like this:

```
  wrappers {
    colorizeOutput 'xterm'
    buildName '#${BUILD_NUMBER}-release'
    artifactoryGenericConfigurator {
      // Repository to deploy to.
      details {
        artifactoryName('artifactory.foo.bar.com')
        artifactoryUrl('https://artifactory.foo.bar.com/artifactory')
        deployReleaseRepository {
          keyFromSelect('')
          keyFromText('')
          dynamicMode(false)
        }
        deploySnapshotRepository {
          keyFromSelect('')
          keyFromText('')
          dynamicMode(false)
        }
        resolveReleaseRepository() {
          keyFromText('')
          keyFromSelect('')
          dynamicMode(false)
        }
        resolveSnapshotRepository() {
          keyFromText('')
          keyFromSelect('')
          dynamicMode(false)
        }
        userPluginKey('')
        userPluginParams('')

        useSpecs(true)
        uploadSpec {
          spec('''{
            "files": [
              {
                  "pattern": "app.tar.gz",
                  "target": "myrepo/app/${BUILD_NUMBER}-release",
                  "flat" : "false"
              }
            ]
          }''')
          filePath(null)
        }
        downloadSpec {
          spec('')
          filePath(null)
        }
      }

      deployPattern('')
      deployBuildInfo(true)
      includeEnvVars(false)
      discardOldBuilds(false)
      discardBuildArtifacts(false)
      multiConfProject(false)
      deployerCredentialsConfig(null)
      resolverCredentialsConfig(null)
      resolverDetails(null)
      resolvePattern(null)
      matrixParams(null)

      envVarsPatterns {
        includePatterns('*')
        excludePatterns('*PASSWORD*,*password*,*secret*,*key*')
      } 
      asyncBuildRetention(false)
      artifactoryCombinationFilter(null)
      customBuildName(null)
      overrideBuildName(false)
    }
  }
```

However, this config always leads to this error, that is a bit confusing, since I do not know which part of my config is wrong here.

> FATAL: No Artifactory server configured for null. Please check your
>   configuration. java.io.IOException: No Artifactory server configured
>   for null. Please check your configuration.    at
>   org.jfrog.hudson.util.RepositoriesUtils.validateServerConfig(RepositoriesUtils.java:191)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.hudson.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.setUp(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:325)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)

Here's an important detail: *if*, after generating my job, I go to the Jenkins configuration page for this job, and save the config without changing anything, *then this config works*. I think I am just using the wrong default values for all the options .

NB: I have to specify all of these, since they are listed as "mandatory" in the API Viewer... [http://jenkins.foo.bar.com/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html](http://enkins/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html)

I have been looking at the [source code for the plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/hudson-artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/plugins/artifactory/generic/ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java), and while I could find some context for my error message, I couldn't diagnose the exact problem in my DSL script.

Comment: Did you install Artifactory plugin in Jenkins and configure the servers?

Comment: Yes I did. In fact I can apply the same configuration manually and successfully build and archive in Artifactory in a Jenkins job.

Comment: Have you followed this link:  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-CreatinganArtifactoryServerInstance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm just working on Job DSL examples.

You need to configure an Artifactory server in [Artifactory Plugin Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ArtifactoryPluginConfiguration).
Then, in `artifactoryName` field, put the server id. `artifactoryUrl` field is not necessary. All other fields, like `useSpecs` should be outside `detail` scope.

If you want to configure repository in your seed job, please change `dynamicMode` to true.

Finally, please notice that there are no snapshot repositories since they are not supported in Artifactory Gradle jobs in Jenkins.

In the end, you'll have something like this:

```
details { // This is the Artifactory deployer details
    artifactoryName SERVER_ID // The server ID from Artifactory Plugin Configuration
    deployReleaseRepository {
        keyFromText 'libs-release-local' // The deploy release repository
        dynamicMode true // true if you want to use `keyFromText`
    }

} // This is the Artifactory resolver details
resolverDetails {
    artifactoryName SERVER_ID // The server ID from Artifactory Plugin Configuration
    resolveReleaseRepository {
        keyFromText 'libs-release' // The resolve release repository
        dynamicMode true // true if you want to use `keyFromText`
    }
}
useSpecs true
...
```

**Update:**

in the latest release v2.15.0 we made some changes that make this configuration a bit easier. For example, the dymamicMode is not necessary now. For more information please refer to our [project examples](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/job-dsl-examples).

Comment: Just the `artifactoryName` needed to match the config, that seems to have fixed it, thanks! It's a bit misleading that the `artifactoryUrl` field would not be necessary.
The snapshot repos and so on (`deploySnapshotRepository `) I have to leave in my config (with null arguments), because these are mandatory parameters unfortunately...

Comment: same player play again after last update:
`ERROR: (mybuild.groovy, line 42) the following options are required and must be specified: deployerDetails, deploymentProperties`